# Mongoose stopped accepting callbacks for some of its functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been using callbacks for .save() and .findOne() for a few days now and just today I encounter these errors:

```
throw new MongooseError('Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback')

MongooseError: Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback
```

and

`MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback`

It's really awkward given that callbacks are still accepted in the docs at least for [.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne).

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else res.render("secrets");
    });
});
```

This is what used to work for me, using express and mongoose. Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: It seems the documentation is not updated. Here's the list of functions that do not support callback anymore: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support

Comment: You should use await with try/catch for this. Also, when creating a new user I would recommend User.create() instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

Since the callback function has been deprecated from now onwards.
If you are using [these](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support) functions with callbacks, use async/await or promises if async functions don't work for you.

```
app.get("/articles", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const articles = await Article.find({ });
    res.send(articles);
    console.log(articles);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 19):

```
// old way (deprecated)

Model.find(function(err, models){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else {
    console.log(models);
  }
});


// new way

Model.find()
.then(function (models) {
  console.log(models);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Mongoose has just made a new update, mongoose has now got rid of callbacks. So that means, now instead of doing this

```js
//Old way ( doesn't work anymore )

data.save((err, result) => {
   if(!err) console.log(result);
})
```

You should do it like this!

```js
//New way ( use this in your projects )

let output;
(async () => {
   output = await data.save();
})
console.log(output);
```

**This also applies for every other mongoose callback**

Comment: you forgot a parenthesis, right? it's a IIFE I guess (..)()

Answer (score 5):

You can either use then catch or async await

**then catch** method:

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**async await** method:

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
};

connectToMongo();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save().then(()=>{
        res.render("secrets");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone whose facing issue connecting to mongodb. Just use async await and you are good to go...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoURI = "Connection URI";

const connectToMongo = async () => {
 mongoose.connect(mongoURI, await console.log("Connected to mongo `Successful")`
    );
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({email:username})
    .then((foundUser) => {
        if(foundUser){
            if(foundUser.password === password){
                res.render("secrets");
            }
        }
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       //When there are errors We handle them here

console.log(err);
       res.send(400, "Bad Request");
   });
      
});
```

This works for me, also im doing the web dev bootcamp by angela yu.

It seems like now you have to use => then and =>catch for the handling

Comment: That's what fixed the error for me. I just don't understand how it changed from one day to another. It was perfectly fine yesterday and when running it today everything was throwing errors. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: yeah it was from one day to other

Comment: I'm also following the same course what you mentioned. I just completed the backend part & now heading towards React. Since Angela Yu explained callback function everywhere, for me it was very difficult to follow her by changing callback to async await or promises. Anyways, happy to see you here.

Answer (score 1):

```
In index.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.mgwgzxk.mongodb.net/test' 

const connectToMongo =  () => {
     mongoose.connect(mongoURI)
     .then( ()=>
        console.log("Connected to mongo Successful")
    )
}


module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this as well and I love all the solutions, though none seemed to match the code from the original question, so I finally figured out the answer that matches the code format. The key is to use `try and catch`

NOTE: I am using controllers so instead of starting with `app.post("/endpoint", (req, res) => {}` I start with `exports.Controller = async...`

```
const EditMyData = mongoose.model("editdata");

exports.postData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const EditData = await new EditMyData({
      editdata: req.body.editdata,
    });
    EditData.save();
    console.log(EditData);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Created",
      EditData,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message:
        "error data was not created",
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

The following code snippet demonstrates the usage of Mongoose models and the `save()` method to save data to a MongoDB database. Let's break it down and explain each part:

1. Defining the Mongoose model:

   ```js
   var messageModel = mongoose.model('message', {
       name: String,
       message: String,
   });
   ```

   In this code, a Mongoose model named `messageModel` is created using the `mongoose.model()` function. The model represents a collection in the MongoDB database and defines the schema for the documents in that collection. In this case, the schema specifies that each document should have a `name` property of type String and a `message` property of type String.
2. Handling the POST request:

   ```js
   app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
       var messageModelObject = new messageModel(req.body);

       messageModelObject.save()
           .then(() => {
               console.log("Message has been saved successfully in the database");
               console.log("This is a post request");
               console.log("Req body: ", req.body);
               messages.push(req.body);
               io.emit('message', req.body);
               res.sendStatus(200);
           })
           .catch((err) => {
               console.log("There was an error saving the msg object to the database");
               console.log("Sending 500 status code");
               res.sendStatus(500);
           });
   });
   ```

   This code handles a POST request to the `/messages` endpoint. It creates a new instance of the `messageModel` using the request body (`req.body`) as the data. The `save()` method is then called on the `messageModelObject` to save the data to the MongoDB database.

   If the save operation is successful, the `.then()` block is executed, logging a success message to the console and performing additional actions such as pushing the message data to an array (`messages`), emitting a `message` event through Socket.io, and sending a 200 status code as the response.

   If there is an error during the save operation, the `.catch()` block is executed, logging an error message to the console and sending a 500 status code as the response.

This code snippet demonstrates how to create a Mongoose model, save data to the database using the `save()` method, and handle the results of the save operation. It is commonly used in Express.js applications to handle the persistence of data submitted through HTTP requests.

Answer (score -2):

**Do this:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

const connectToMongo = async () => {
try {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI) 
    console.log('Mongo connected')
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit()
}
}
module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

this will work!