# mongoose code showing error of a call ack function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

```
app.post ('/create_contact',function(req,res) 
{
  contact.create({
    name :req.body.name,
    phone:req.body.phone
  },function(err,newContact)
  {
    if(err){console.log('error in creating a contact!');
    return;}

  console.log('********',newContact);
  return res.redirect('back');
  });
});
```

Errors:

```
throw new MongooseError('Model.create() no longer accepts a callback');
          ^
MongooseError: Model.create() no longer accepts a callback
```

I tried this code but again showing error

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting but it was a mess; perhaps you will want to [edit] to include a full traceback. Also, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. What have you done to debug the problem; what did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with `async await`

```
app.post('/create_contact', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const newContact = await contact.create(req.body);
    console.log('********', newContact);
    return res.redirect('back');
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('error in creating a contact!');
  }
});
```

Comment: hey! Thanks this code works and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has dropped support for callbacks to some of it’s methods (The create method is one of them). You can check out this [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support) to see more about it. And instead of using callbacks, using async/await syntax and wrap it with a try/catch block to handle errors that might happen on creation of a new document.

Check this [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions). Your question will be flagged.