# mongoose error: model.find() no longer accept call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

Here is my full app.js code.

```
//jshint esversion:6 

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to your todolist!"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new item."
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item."
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){

      if (foundItems.length === 0) {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully savevd default items to DB.");
          }
        });
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
      }
  });
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);

  List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList){
    if (!err){
      if (!foundList){
        //Create a new list
        const list = new List({
          name: customListName,
          items: defaultItems
        });
      
        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + customListName);
      } else {
      //Show an existing list
        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
      }
    }
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Today"){
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList){
      foundList.items.push(item);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  const listName = req.body.listName;

  if (listName === "Today") {
    Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Successfully deleted checked item.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
  } else {
    List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull: {items: {_id: checkedItemId}}}, function(err, foundList){
      if (!err){
        res.redirect("/" + listName);
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Cannot understand where the error is!

The error is:

```
Model.find() no longer accept a call back.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions) help in any way?

Comment: Need to rewrite the code using promises - not callbacks, this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

occurs because starting from Mongoose version 6, the find() method no longer accepts a callback function as the second argument. Instead, it returns a promise that you can handle using **.then()** or **async/await** syntax.

**To fix the error, you can modify your code to use promises instead of callbacks.**

Here's the updated code:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   Item.find({})
      .then(foundItems => {
          res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItem: foundItems});
    })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
  });
```

});

In the updated code, Item.find({}) returns a promise, and you can use the **.then()** method to handle the resolved value, which in this case is the **foundItems** array. If an error occurs during the query execution, you can handle it using the **.catch()** method.

> Make sure you have a compatible version of Mongoose installed in your
> project. If you're using an older version of Mongoose (pre-6.0), you
> can continue using the callback syntax without modifying your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async function instead:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
const allItems = await Item.find();
console.log("Found " + allItems.length + " numbers of items in the database.");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message is self-explanatory: A **callback** function is a function that you pass as an argument to another function, and that will be called/executed later on after a certain event.

In your specific case, the `find` method doesn't accept anymore callback functions so you need to remove `function(err, foundItems)...` from `Item.find`:

```js
Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
  // Code
});
```

For more info about it, kindly check this link to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find)