# Model.find() no longer accepts a callback in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am currently learning Mongoose from Dr. Angela Yu's Course , however since mongoose has changed the syntax of find and other several functions, it is throwing above error

Here is the JavaScript Code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
var items = [];

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todoList", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema); // Items = collection name & ItemScema = Schema

// const <constantName> = new <ModelName> ({
//     <fieldName> : <fieldData>
//         })

//Some Default Items for the list
const Item1 = new Item({
    name: "Welcome To Your To-Do-List!"
})

const Item2 = new Item({
    name: "Hit the + button to add a new Item"
})

const Item3 = new Item({
    name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item"
})

const defaultItems = [Item1, Item2, Item3];


// Item.find(AllItems){
//     .then(function(){
//         console.log("Here are the items");
//     }) 
//     .catch(function(err){
//         console.log(err);
//     })
// };





// Item.deleteMany( {name:"<-- Hit this to delete an item"})
//  .then(function(){
//     console.log("Deleted")
//  })
//  .catch(function(err){
//     console.log(err);
// })



// Item.insertMany(defaultItems)
//       .then(function () {
//         console.log("Successfully saved defult items to DB");
//       })
//       .catch(function (err) {
//         console.log(err);
//       });
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    var today = new Date();

    var options = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", year: "numeric" , month: "numeric" };

    var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options);

   Item.find({}, function(err, FoundItems){
    console.log(FoundItems);
    res.render("list", {kindOfDay: day, newItem: FoundItems});

   })
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var item = req.body.newItem;
 
    items.push(item);

    res.redirect("/");

})
    app.listen(3000, function () { //or process.env.PORT || 2000
        console.log("Server started on port 3000");
    })
```

The EJS code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> <%= kindOfDay%></h1> 
  <ul>
    <li>Buy Food</li>
    <li>Cook Food</li>
    <li>Eat Food</li>
    <!-- <li><%= newItem %></li>  -->
    <%for (var i = 0; i < newItem.length; i++){ %>
        <li><%= newItem[i] %></li>
   <% }  %>
 
  </ul>

  <form class="" action = "/" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "newItem">
    <button type = "submit" name = "button">Add</button>
  </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a to-do-List app and hence **I need to render all the list items to my To-do-list** ,  I have been trying to learn the alternatives but since I am a newbie I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose stopped accepting callbacks for some of its functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
async function getItems(){

  const Items = await Item.find({});
  return Items;

}

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

  var today = new Date();

  var options = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", year: "numeric" , 
  month: "numeric" };

  var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options);

  getItems().then(function(FoundItems){
    
    res.render("list", {kindOfDay: day, newItem:FoundItems});

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank You so much!! I appreciate your time and effort you took to solve my problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

well i had the same issue so this is how i resolve it (just in case):

first, im pretty sure you already looked but here is the link of the doc:

since i'm also a newbie i couldnt get why `await MyModel.find({});`
doesn't work, that's because i didnt use it in a async function. remember `await` need to be inside a async function

so let's say you created fruit schema and fruit model and add an example of fruit like Angela did in the videos

```js
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  name: String,
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  },
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "peach",
  rating: 10,
  review: "yummyyy"

});
```

let's say we want to get only the name of our fruit object. that's how you do it:

```js
async function myfruits() {
    const fruits= await Fruit.find({});
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
        console.log(fruit.name);
    });
}
myfruits();
```

we got the fruits array which is an array of fruit objects then using foreach we got the names of our fruits

Comment: Correct, i went through the docs and updated my code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {

  var today = new Date();

  var options = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", year: "numeric" , 
  month: "numeric" };

  var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options);

  Item.find({}).then(function(FoundItems){
    
    res.render("list", {kindOfDay: day, newItem:FoundItems});

  })
   .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it async just add Model.**find({})**.then function(), this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Angela Yu is using mongoose 5.3.4, i had same issue solved it by following --> npm uninstall mongoose and then npm i mongoose@5.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Change your mongoose version in to 5.0 its is not support from 6.0 or upper version

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the existing mongoose by npm uninstall mongoose and then reinstall it by npm install mongoose@5.3.4 (using a specific version of mongoose) then your works perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of mongoose, Mongoose models provide several static helper functions for CRUD operations. Each of these functions returns a mongoose Query object.
Unfortunately, these helper functions(e.g. Model.find(),Model.insertMany(),Model.updateOne()) no longer accept the callback as a parameter. But the return values of them are Query or Promise Object, we can use the .then() method to fix this issue.

My solution is as follows:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    var today = new Date();

    var options = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", year: "numeric" , month: "numeric" };

    var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options);

    Item.find({}).then(foundItems => {
        console.log(foundItems);
        res.render("list", {kindOfDay: day, newItem: FoundItems});

    })
    .catch(err => {console.error('there was an error', err)});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was trying to do a filter using find:

```
let output = await Item.find(item => item.id === Id); //this threw the error
```

So I changed it to:

```
let output = Item.find({}).then(items => {
      return items.filter(item => item.id === Id);
    });
```

And it worked. I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Use this promise method by then and catch

```
User.findById(id)
.then(user => {
 done(null, user);
})
.catch(err => {
  done(err, null);
});
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this message will come when you are using a Mongoose version above 6. so I would suggest two options. The first one is to downgrade your Mongoose version(which is not the best solution)
to do that just run the following command.

```
npm i monggose@6
```

The second solution is to use a try-catch statement.

```
Item.find({}).then((result) =>console.log(result)).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem got solved by This code works for me as of 7/21/2023

```
   async function logAllFruits() {
    try {
      // Fetch all documents from the Fruit collection
      const allFruits = await Fruit.find();
  
      // Log the entire collection of documents
      console.log('All Fruits:', allFruits);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }
  
  logAllFruits();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here Read This Mongoose new version Documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

and Read the documentation of 'async' functions and 'promises' one too.

The answer you are looking for is in the above docs, pls read them carefully and you will be able to do it yourself. If you still struggle pls. message me by replying this comment.

Also I am also learning MERN Stack for same Course.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I Appreciate your time and efforts and yes I'll surely go through the documentation.