# Problem regarding call back function in mongoose

Tags: javascript, ejs

I can't run a callback function using the post.find tag.Whenever I run nodemon app.js it shows erroe like this:

```
D:\Blog-with-Database-Starting-Files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2048
    throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
    ^

MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback       
    at Function.find (D:\Blog-with-Database-Starting-Files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2048:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Blog-with-Database-Starting-Files\app.js:57:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)  
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)  
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here are my app.js file and ejs files :

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blogDB", {useNewUrlParser: true})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String
};

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  Post.find({}).then(function(err, foundPosts){
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      res.render("home", {
          homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, 
          posts: foundPosts
      });
    }
  })
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about", {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact", {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
  res.render("home", {
    startingContent: homeStartingContent,
    posts: posts
  });
})
app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  post.save()

  res.redirect("/");

});

app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  posts.forEach(function(post){
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

    if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
      res.render("post", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p> <%= startingContent %> </p>


  <%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

    <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
    <p>
    <%=post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..."%>
    <a href="/posts/<%=post.title%>">Read More</a>
    </p>


    <% }) %>


<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

I have changed the callback function format in app.get("/", function(req, res){} part as Post.find({}).then(function(foundPosts) but it's still not working.Please suggest any alternate way to do so in order to make the callback function run properly.

Comment: "but it's still not working" means what?

Comment: I am not able to host the site at localhost due to the problem with the callback function as in the terminal it shows that app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mongoose are you using? In v6 and up, [they have stopped support for callback functions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution) to eliminate mixing promises and callbacks. For example this will throw an error.

```
Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
  res.render("home", {
    startingContent: homeStartingContent,
    posts: posts
  });
})
```

You need to use `async/await` or Promises instead -
*async/await*

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res){
  try {
    const foundPosts = await Post.find({})
    res.render("home", {
            homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, 
            posts: foundPosts
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }})

>>> OR >>>>>
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  Post.find({}).then((foundPosts) => {
      res.render("home", {
          homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, 
          posts: foundPosts
      })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    }
  ))
});
```

Might have missed a bracket/closing parentheses, but you get the idea.

Comment: Its still showing the same error.

Comment: the async/await version should work, since it's not a callback function - here's some more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655652/model-find-no-longer-accepts-a-callback-in-mongoose and the up-to-date docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find()

Answer (score 0):

Here is this code, it works!

```
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blogDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
};
//Schema 

const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String
};

//Mongoose Model 
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  
  Post.find({})
    .then((posts) => {
      res.render("home", 
      {
        startingContent: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts
      }) 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      })
});
  
  


app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact", {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get('/compose', (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post('/compose', (req, res) =>{
  
  //Usage oof mongoose model
  const post = new Post ({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  const saveToPosTDb = 
  async () => {
    await post.save();
    console.log('Compose saved');
  };
  // call the function 
  saveToPosTDb();
  //redirect to
  res.redirect('/');

});

app.get('/posts/:postId', (req, res) => {
  
  //const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  const showPost =
  async () => {
    await Post.findOne({_id:requestedPostId})
    .then (post => {
      
      res.render('post', {
      title:post.title,
      content: post.content
    })
      console.log('Post found');
    })
    .catch (err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  };

  showPost();

  

});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the Promises correctly. One option, is to replace the if control flow statement with .then and .catch:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Post.find({}).then(
    function(foundPosts) {
      res.render("home", {
          homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, 
          posts: foundPosts
      });
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
```

or,

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Post.find({}).then(
    foundPosts => {
      res.render("home", {
          homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, 
          posts: foundPosts
      })
  }).catch(
    err => console.log(err)   //No semicolon at the end of the arrow functions
  );
});
```

Here is it with async/ await:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  try {
    const foundPosts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("home", {
      homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent,
      posts: foundPosts
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
'''
Good luck!
```