# MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

here is my code

```
Fruit.find(function(err,fruits){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }
   else{
     console.log(fruits);
   }
});
```

here is the error

MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose stopped accepting callbacks for some of its functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions)

Answer (score 2):

after spending my 2,3 hours i resolved this problem, for understanding how did it work you should already know  promises,async await,then catch

```
Fruit.find().then(function(fruits,err){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
else{
    console.log(fruits);
}
```

});

Comment: Well done for working it out on your own. There was a bug with your error handling code, I edited your post to fix it ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76027203/revisions)). Feel free to "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to recent changes implemented by Mongoose, you cannot use callback functions inside certain methods like Model.find() anymore. `Fruit.find(function(err, fruits){})` will not work because `function(err, fruits){}` is a callback function. Instead, they encourage you to use newer techniques, namely Promises and Async-await. Here are few possible solutions for your problem:

```
Fruit.find().then(
    function(fruits) {
        console.log(fruits);
    }).catch(
        function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        );
```

Or shorter, using arrow functions:

```
Fruit.find().then(
    fruits => console.log(fruits)
    ).catch(
        err => console.log(err)
        );
```

(make sure you do not use semicolons to end the console.log lines in the example above, or it will not work)

If this is a part of larger block of code consider the following example:

```
app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const fruits = await Fruit.find();
        console.log(fruits);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Hope, it helps.