# How to make a post request in Node with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was following a tutorial(https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/building-restful-apis-with-node-js-and-express-a9f648219f5b) to build an API but it's from 2 years ago and I can't quite seem to change the code to accommodate more recent updates in the library. I'm able to get the get request to work  but not the post. When I do

```
.post(addNewCoordinates);
```

I get "Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]"

Which the internet said to add async await which I did. Am I missing something else??

The setup I have with the mongodb is I created a database in the compass GUI and that's literally it.(i technically have a collection in the database)

Here is my index.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import routes from './src/routes/coordinatesRoutes';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
routes(app)
const PORT = 1234;
// Will print at localhost:{Port}
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.send(`Node and express server running on port ${PORT}`)
)
// Will print in terminal
app.listen(PORT, () =>
console.log(`Your server is running on port ${PORT}`))

// Database Setup

// mongoose connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/coordinates', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})
//bodyparser setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

coordinatesController.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { InputDataSchema } from '../models/coordinatesModel'
const InputData = mongoose.model('InputData', InputDataSchema);
const addNewCoordinates = async  (req,res) => {
  let newCoordinates =  new InputData(req.body);
   await newCoordinates.save((err, coordinates) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err)
    }
    res.json(coordinates)
  })
}

export default addNewCoordinates;
```

coordinatesModel.js:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
export const InputDataSchema = new Schema({
  latitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: "Enter latitude"
  },
  longitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: "Enter longitude"
  },
  altitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: "Enter altitude"
  },
  ecef: {
    type: Array
  },
  created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})
```

coordinatesRoute.js

```js
import addNewCoordinates  from '../controllers/coordinatesController'
const routes = (app) => {
    //create route for donations
    app.route('/lla')
      //create get request
      .get((req, res) =>
      res.send('GET request successful!'))
      //create post request
      .post((req, res) =>
      res.set('POST request successful!'));
      // This crashes and gives me a Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] so I'm just trying to focus on getting a post without really any data.
     //.post(addNewCoordinates);

    // create a new route so you can get these donation entries by their ID's
    app.route('/lla/:timestamp')
      //create put request
      .put((req, res) =>
      res.send('PUT request successful!'))
      //create delete request
      .delete((req, res) =>
      res.send('DELETE request successful'))
  }
  export default routes;
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You're importing the callback wrong. Either `export addNewCoordinates` (without default) or `import addNewCoordinates` (without brackets)

Comment: @GuyIncognito that first one should be `export { addNewCoordinates }` or `export const addNewCoordinates = async (req, res) => ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways in which exports can happen in JavaScript, namely,`default exports` and `named exports`. Since there are two ways of exporting , so are corresponding ways of importing too.

When you're exporting from your **coordinatesController.js** it's actually a `default export`, whereas the import in **coordinatesRoute.js** is an import for `named export`.

The correct way of importing a default export would be without `{..}` or

> import addNewCoordinates  from
> '../controllers/coordinatesController'

This could also be resolved by exporting it as `named`.

For more you can refer: [MDN Docs for export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: I still get the error even with removing the curly bracket (updated code above)
MongooseError: Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback
    at model.save

Comment: OP, that's a completely different error, not related to the question. Kindly refer different answers at the forum to resolve this. If your original query is resolved, you can accept an answer and close the discussion. Feel free to post your newfound error in a different post, let's keep it organised and to the point.

Comment: and for your last error, feel free to refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions

Comment: Oh wow thanks, you solved both my issues haha!