# mongoose code not working i specific area

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

am writing a mongoose code, but i get an error when am using find() method, the error says the functions is no longer accepting a callback.

tried to solve it with other functions but nothing worked

[code image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpRkX.png)

thats the error type :

MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose stopped accepting callbacks for some of its functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions)

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose 7.x, the support for callback methods was dropped. You can find the migration instructions from 6.x to 7.x here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support

What does that mean for your current method? Nothing too complicated. You just need to use `async/await`

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myTask = await task.find({});
    // ...rest of your code
  } catch (error) {
    // ...handle error here
  }
});
```