# MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback at Function in 2024

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

my codes here

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const UserModel = require("./models/Users");

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://user123:<password>@cluster0.16wokcq.mongodb.net/merntutorial?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);

app.get("/getUsers", (req, res) => {
   UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});


app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER RUNS PERFECTLY!");
});
```

I'm a beginner guy about mern stack project, I know it's common error about mongoose but I search so many solutions but I these didn't work for me: (

Comment: Callbacks have been dropped for a while now. You need to use `then/catch` blocks or `async/await`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75586474/21972629).

Comment: thanks man, I changed if else to then/catch block, it's solved, god bless you

Answer (score 0):

Syntax correct, I think you are facing some async await problem ,so use async await, while calling data ,if Not work then let me know ,I will provide more solutions

Comment: I don't know in where can I use async await, I tried like this but I get same error again,

in 3001 server everythings works fine, but in 3001/getUsers endpoint I getting this error :(
   

`  app.get("/getUsers", async (req, res) => {
 await   UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});     `